# How do I find the unique solution to this linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The question is based on an exercise in linear algebra:

> [image]

**THOUGHTS**:

By looking at the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant), I know that a unique solution occurs when $c \neq 2$ or $-3$ since a square matrix is singular if and only if its determinant is $0$ (see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)). How can I really find what this solution is concretely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The system has a unique solution if you can invert the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1\\
1&c&3\\
2&3&c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And the solution is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\X_2\\X_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1\\
1&c&3\\
2&3&c
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: yes if the determinant is nonzero ..... but my question is can I find this unique solution concretely?

Comment: yes, of course, by inverting the matrix

Comment: but there are $c's$ in the matrix

Comment: Yes, and there will be c's in the inverse matrix as well. Just find the inverse treating the c's as variables

Comment: got it :) thanks!

Comment: No problem! Hopefully the new edits help

Comment: Can you tell me the final form of the inverse matrix so that I can check if my solution is correct when I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

If, in your system, you subtract the first line from the second one and twice the first line from the third line, you get$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}X_1+X_2-X_3=1\\(c-1)X_2+4X_3=1\\X_2+(c+2)X_3=1.\end{array}\right.$$Now, if you subtract the third line times $c-1$ from the second one, you get$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}X_1+X_2-X_3=1\\(-c^2-c+6)X_3=-c+2\\X_2+(c+2)X_3=1.\end{array}\right.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I will try to see if I can

Comment: The next step is to deduce that$$X_3=\frac{-c+2}{-c^2-c+6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

To obtain in practice the solutions when they exist, you can start from the augmented matrix  and use row operations until the submatrix corresponding to the l.h.s. is the unit matrix. The vector of solutions is then the last column.

Here is how it goes, if my computations are correct:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&-1&1\\1&c&3&2\\2&3&c&3
\end{array}\right]&\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&-1&1\\0&c-1&4&1\\0&1&c+2&1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&-1&1\\0&1&c+2&1\\0&c-1&4&1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow \\[1ex]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&-1&1\\0&1&c+2&1\\0&c-1&4&1
\end{array}\right]&\rightsquigarrow 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&-1&1\\0&1&c+2&1\\0&0&\substack{6-c-c^2\\=-(c-2)(c+3)}&2-c
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&-1&1\\0&1&c+2&1\\0&0&1&\frac1{c+3}
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow \\[1ex]
\text{(we suppose here  }c\ne2,-3)\\[1ex]\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&0&\frac{c+4}{c+3}\\0&1&0&\frac1{c+3}\\0&0&1&\frac1{c+3}
\end{array}\right]&\rightsquigarrow\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&\frac{1}{c+3}\\0&0&1&\frac1{c+3}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align}

Comment: I think the solution should be $X_2=X_3=\frac1{c+3}$ and $X_1=1$.

Comment: Possibly. I did not guarantee the final result and it's a bit too late here to check. Did you check your result in the equations?

Comment: Yes I've checked my derivation twice! I can't find any mistake but I await for your cofirmation too. Bye

Comment: @user yes your solution exactly what I get

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow morning.  For me, the important point was to illustrate the algorithm – without errors if possible.

Comment: @Bernard in the second row the last entry should be positive not negative in the matrix before last

Comment: @Secretly: exercise suggested: find out where I've mage computation errors.

Comment: consequently the last entry in the last matrix in the first row is incorrect

Comment: By the way, thank you so much for your efforts!

Comment: I think I see now \I repeated inadvertently a copy-paste. I'l fix that.

Comment: That's it, at last. It saved one step. Thanks!

Comment: This also shows that the system has infinitely many solutions for $c=2$ and no solution for $c=-3$, so it's *much* better than just computing the inverse when it exists.

Comment: @Jack: I've just voted to reopen the post too.

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed by elimination for the augmented matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&1\\
1&c&3&2\\
2&3&c&3
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&1\\
0&c-1&4&1\\
0&1&c+2&1
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&1\\
0&c-1&4&1\\
0&0&(c+2)(c-1)-4&c-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&1\\
0&c-1&4&1\\
0&1&c+2&1
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&1\\
0&c-1&4&1\\
0&0&(c-2)(c+3)&c-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

and obtain all from that.

Notably form the third row we obtain that the system is consistent for $x\neq 2$ and $x\neq -3$ therefore we obtain

$$\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&1\\
0&c-1&4&1\\
0&0&c+3&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and we obtain

- from the third row $X_3=\frac 1{c+3}$
- from the second row $X_2=\frac{1-4X_3}{c-1}=\frac{c+3-4}{(c-1)(c-3)}=\frac 1{c+3}$
- from the first row $X_1=1-X_2+X_3=1$

Comment: how can you obtain all from that ?

Comment: From the third line we need that $(c+2)(c-1)-4=c^2+c-6=(c3)(c-2)\neq 0$ which gives the condition for the existence of the unique solution.

Comment: this is not my question

Comment: Then once we fix $c$ we can obtain from below $X_3$ then $X_2$ and finally $X_1$.

Comment: how can you obtain $X_{3}$ could you please show me the details?

Comment: How did you obtain your third matrix? what did you do for the third row?

Comment: The first step for row 3 is $R_3-2R_1$ and for row 2 $R_2-R_1$. The seocond step for row 3 is $(c-1)R_3-R_2$.

Comment: @Secretly Refer to [Row redution method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Row_reduction) for more details.

Comment: My $X_{2}$ is $$\frac{c-2}{(c+2)(c -1) - 4}$$ is it correct?

Comment: yes I calculated this value and I found what I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: And also I get $X_{1} = 1$

Comment: Yes I know I am asking about the concrete value

Comment: @Secretly To recap we have $$X_3=X_2=\frac1{c+3}$$ $$X_1=1$$